# Is it possible to read out the console.logs if i compiled my sencha-app to an ios-simulator?

Tags: ios, logging, sencha-touch, ios-simulator

I compiled my sencha-app through "sencha app package.." to an iphone-simulator.

Now i wanna look into my console.logs, so that i can verify my client-programm behaviour. I opened the system-protocol but i can't find my logs. Maybe somebody can help me out here?

tia && regards
  noircc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a couple of options for this. The easiest is to use the remote inspector from Webkit Nightly. All the steps required are explained here:

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari/